# Woocommerce : read [max_qty] using backorder

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to allow order when product is out of stock and read the quantity in stock. If i set allow backorder the following code with [max_qty] is always 0 and not works:

```
 if ($product->product_type == 'variable') {
        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $key) {
        $attr_string = '';
            foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value) {
                                $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
            }
            if ( $key['max_qty'] > 0 ) { echo '<style> body span.swatch.swatch-label.swatch-' . implode(', ', $attr_string) . ' {opacity:1!important;     background: #484848!important; color: #fff!important;}</style>'; } else {  }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this code:

```
if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )){

    // Get the available variations for the variable product
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // Initializing variables
    $variations_count = count($available_variations);
    $loop_count = 0;

    // Iterating through each available product variation
    foreach( $available_variations as $key => $values ) {
        $loop_count++;
        // Get the term color name
        $attribute_color = $values['attributes']['attribute_pa_size'];
        $wp_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_color, 'pa_size' );
        $term_name = $wp_term->name; // Color name

        // Get the variation quantity
        $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $values['variation_id'] );
        $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity(); // Stock qty

        // The display
        $separator_string = " // ";
        $separator = $variations_count < $loop_count ? $separator_string : '';

       // echo $term_name . ' = ' . $stock_qty . $separator . '<br>';

         if ( $stock_qty > 0 ) { echo '<style> body span.swatch.swatch-label.swatch-' . $term_name.  '{opacity:1!important;     background: #484848!important; color: #fff!important;}</style>' ;} else {  }
    }

}
```